# MySQL Join, including all values from return seperated values

Tags: mysql

I am working with a table. For the sakes of illustration:

```
mysql> SELECT users.id, username, REPLACE(selected_groups, '\r', ', '), groups.id, groups.label FROM users LEFT JOIN groups ON users.selected_groups;
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+
| id | username               | REPLACE(selected_groups, '\r', ', ') | id   | label         |
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+
|  7 | Greg                   | 1, 2, 3,                             |    1 | Administrator |
|  7 | Greg                   | 1, 2, 3,                             |    2 | Member        |
|  7 | Greg                   | 1, 2, 3,                             |    3 | Banned        |
|  8 | Steve                  | 1, 2,                                |    1 | Administrator |
|  8 | Steve                  | 1, 2,                                |    2 | Member        |
|  8 | Steve                  | 1, 2,                                |    3 | Banned        |
|  9 | Steve The Banned Admin | 1, 3,                                |    1 | Administrator |
|  9 | Steve The Banned Admin | 1, 3,                                |    2 | Member        |
|  9 | Steve The Banned Admin | 1, 3,                                |    3 | Banned        |
| 10 | Example man            | 1, 2, 3,                             |    1 | Administrator |
| 10 | Example man            | 1, 2, 3,                             |    2 | Member        |
| 10 | Example man            | 1, 2, 3,                             |    3 | Banned        |
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I have a users table and a groups table. Within the users table is a 'selected_groups' column, within which the related groups are defined using return seperated values ('\r').

The problem is I'm not so sure on how I can return each required label in the label field. The resulting output would ideally be something like this:

```
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------+
| id | username               | REPLACE(selected_groups, '\r', ', ') | id   | groups.label                  |
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------+
|  7 | Greg                   | 1, 2, 3,                             |    1 | Administrator, Member, Banned |
|  8 | Steve                  | 1, 2,                                |    1 | Administrator, Member         |
|  9 | Steve The Banned Admin | 1, 3,                                |    1 | Administrator, Banned         |
| 10 | Example man            | 1, 2, 3,                             |    1 | Administrator, Member, Banned |
+----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------------+
```

Do you think this is possible, and if so, does anyone have any tips/solution for me?

Many thanks,
Ricky

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

With a `group by` clause on the user id and username and a `group_concat` on label, it should do the trick.

I'm thinking something like :

```
SELECT users.id, username, REPLACE(selected_groups, '\r', ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT groups.label)
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN groups ON users.selected_groups;
GROUP BY users.id, username
```

(this is not tested, so maybe it will require some modifications)

edit : I removed the groups.id from the query, since it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work this way. All that group_concat seems to do in this instance is return ALL of the group labels for each user (as if each user had 1\r2\r3\r in the selected_groups field).

Comment: strange, it should work... I haven't access to a mysql server in the next hours, but I'll check later on.